# JavaScript and typescript shared snippets in vscode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-extensions

I have created quite a lot of custom JavaScript snippets in [VsCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode).
Recently, I started working on a project in typescript and, *not* unexpectedly, the JavaScript snippets do not work in typescript files.

Is there a way to create "shared" snippets that I could use both in JavaScript and typescript? (apart from copying the snippet definition files every time I create a custom snippet)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can create global snippets and scope them:

- From command palette `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`
- `New Global Snippets File`

---

```json
"console.log": {
    "scope": "typescript,javascript,typescriptreact,javascriptreact",
    "prefix": "cl",
    "body": "console.log($0);",
},
```